# Java Threads producer consumer program

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am trying to write a producer consumer program in Java where producer inserts 3 numbers in a Queue and Consumer removes these numbers from the queue. I have implemented my own Queue based on my own Linkedlist implementation.

When I run my code my producer terminates but my consumer never terminates. I am not able to figure out why

```
public class ProdConMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();
    queue.setLimit(3);
    Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(queue));
    Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(queue));

    producer.start();
    consumer.start();


    try {
        producer.join();
        System.out.println("Producer: " + producer.getState());
        consumer.join();

        System.out.println("Consumer: " + consumer.getState());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(queue.list.toString());

}


}



public class Producer implements Runnable {

MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();
Random random = new Random();
public Producer(MyQueue queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10) {

        synchronized (queue) {
            if (queue.getSize() < queue.getLimit()) {
                int value = random.nextInt(500);
                queue.enqueue(value);
                System.out.println("Inserted: " + value);
                queue.notify();
            } else {
                try {
                    queue.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        i++;
    }
  }
}


public class Consumer implements Runnable {

  MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();

  public Consumer(MyQueue queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

  @Override
  public void run() {

     while (true) {
        synchronized (queue) {

            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                {
                    try {
                        queue.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                int value = queue.dequeue();
                System.out.println("Removed:        " + value);
                queue.notify();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Consumer` never terminates because you are using infinite loop `while (true)`

Comment: Where is your `MyQueue`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a stop condition to that *while(true)* loop in the consumer, otherwise it will never finish. You can do it in the *while* condition itself:

```
while(shouldConsume()) { 
    // consume ...
}
```

or by breaking the infinite loop if the condition is reached:

```
while(true) { 
    // consume ...

    if (shouldStopConsume()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

And then you just have to implement those methods with the stop condition that fits your use case.

Comment: I see, Thank you. It works for me now.
 
Queue Class -     public volatile boolean doneProcessing; (Instance variable)
Producer class - queue.doneProcessing = true; (after exiting from while loop)
Consumer class - while (!queue.doneProcessing)